# Shell_exec with git pull?

Tags: php, git, exec

I am setting up a github account, to work on a small project with some friends.
I would like to have my home machine able to do a git pull via php, so that we just have to call this small php file for the machine to be up to date.

As of right now :

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('git help');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

This works perfectly and I get the output, I am in the right directory, so git pull should work just as well, but I get a hanging page, no error, nothing.

Any idea ?

**EDIT :** A few precisions, the repo is pretty small, around 300K, it takes only a few seconds from the command line. I also tried shell_exec("dir"), and I am in the right directory. I am running the default installation of xampp on Windows 7 x64, if I can be precise enough :)

Comment: How long does it take to pull the remote repo? I suspect you are just timing out.

Comment: thanks, i also have a webproject using git while developing on another computer. after merging my master offline i always had to connect via ssh just to call "git pull origin master". now i solved it via a php script i call. the problem of course was that php was run as apache_mod. running as fcgi solved it. :)

Comment: A collection of Considerations when attempting to run `git pull` from php ... http://jondavidjohn.com/b/7m

Comment: Please, check out this workaround that might be usefull for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository/67889529#67889529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest exploring [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) , as well as making sure your git pull does not stop if the user disconnects via [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php). Even running from a gigabit connected server, some repositories just take a while to clone.

Also, check PHP's working directory, and **ensure** the user running PHP has privileges to write to the repo. If you ran this via CLI and it 'just works', its a good chance that PHP was running without appropriate privileges when accessed via whatever web server you are using.

If you `chmod` the destionation directory as `777` and it works, there's a very good chance that you need to recompile apache/php for suexec support. Please, don't just leave it as 777 if that is the case :)

Either way, time out and user aborts are still valid considerations, even after you get it working.

Comment: The thing is, from the command line, the command takes a mere second, the repository is very small. And even if I let it run for a few minutes, nothing.
The working directory is the right one as the php script is called from the root directory of the project. (I also tried shell_exec dir, just to be sure).

Comment: I'm running under Windows, so no chmod. But the question of privileges is a good one, I'll look it up.
I'll add time limit and ignore user abort as soon as I've got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

So, to answer my own question.

It was in fact a permission problem (thanks tim), from the PHP CLI, the script was working.

The problem was that the service php installation is using some strange permissions.
**So you/I need to start the PHP server via the command line (or in this case the Xampp control panel).**

Now it's working, giving me the "Already up-to-date." answer I was waiting for :)