# How to automatically update your application?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, controls, version

Hi for a research I have to make sure the application I will make stays always up to date. I'm quite a beginner so I thought I would ask here, what is the best way to ensure that an application stays stable and up to date even after its release??

Like is there some tool you can use to let the application update itself automatic or if there some command for that in an version control?

Thanks for reading

Comment: I think this thread may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository

Comment: oh wow this is great, just what I wanted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: auto pull from repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository)