# How to display Git Log updates automatically

Tags: git, github, terminal

I typically like to have a terminal window open while I'm working displaying the git log of whatever branch I'm working in.

Is there a way of improving the workflow of this and getting the log to update automatically with any new commits?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to run it through `watch`, which would by default update it every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try watch this.

[stackexchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1274785/how-to-see-git-log-automatic-refresh)

you might need to create a script that would show you the git log and refresh every 1 second

Comment: Yep, that's the one!

Answer (score 0):

Any script should take into account that if you want to get up-to-date information from remote branches you should issue 
`git fetch` before the `git log` command

Comment: This would make sense for remote-tracking branches, but does not really fit what's asked, because OP wants to see the log for the branch he's working on, which is by definition local and won't be in any way impacted by a `fetch`. It would be different with a `pull` but... let's not even enter the [perilous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository) "reasons for/against an automated pull" debate ^^

Comment: I have to say I don't understand why should a track in the background my own work.
I committed the changes and usually aware on my own actions? 
I would be more concerned about commits from other team members that may conflict and want to catch them as early as possible

Comment: Totally with you on this. How hard is it to type in a two-letters alias once in a while?