# Git: Enforce pull before merge

Tags: git

Sometimes, in my team, a developer will forget to pull from master before merging. We don’t really do code reviews at this point, which brings up my question:

Is there a way to enforce that before merging Branch A into Branch B, Branch A has to contain the last commit of Branch B?

**EDITS**

I’m looking for an automated code review process where the only requirement would be to contain the last commit of the target branch.

I had a look at [branch protection](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-protected-branches#branch-protection-settings). But it unfortunately doesn’t seem to help with my specific case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: auto pull from repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [branch protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864405/how-to-restrict-access-to-master-branch-on-git)

Comment: @R4444 I’m not really looking for an auto pull. I wouldn’t want the developer in branch A to be disturbed but periodic pulls.

Comment: @Skam I had a look at branch protection, but it doesn’t seem to offer what I’m looking for. https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-protected-branches#branch-protection-settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, a [required status check](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-required-status-checks) is exactly what you want. Suppose `master` is the branch you want to protect. You can set it so you can't push to `master` directly. if a branch `feature/foo` is out of date but I want to merge it in, then I can enforce that my branch must be updated with `master`. As a heads up, you must be an administration on the repository to setup required status checks for a repository.

Answer (score 0):

After review is finished instead of pressing buttons on UI you can push to `master` manually either from command line or from IDE. If someone's pushed to master already you'll get an error, so you'll have to incorporate `origin/master` commits into your local history.

GitHub has "Allow merge commits" in the settings and if you uncheck it - your team won't be able to create those automated merges. But they'll still be able to either squash or rebase (at leat 1 option must stay checked) which means they still can push to master w/o pulling changes to feature branch first. So you'll have to talk to them and simply ask not to use UI.