# Force git pull on existing repositories all around

Tags: git, shell, github

I have a repository with bash aliases on my GH account. Since I am logging in to multiple servers with SSH, I could set pull the repository on each server I am in and make it work.

However upon any change (not so frequent, but still) I would have to log in to every server and do a `git pull` which is kinda tedious.

Is it possible to create some kind of push so that upon each repo update, `git pull` is automatically made? Or some other solution which would provide a higher automation?

Comment: Many git repository hosting systems, such as gitlab and github, support webhooks. You will, however, need a web server listening on those servers to have something to call into. Perhaps a schedule on each server would be enough? It wouldn't be immediate, but that depends on how frequent you execute the pull.

Comment: Do you do **only** the git pull?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: auto pull from repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository)