# Is it possible to have multiple gitlab-runners all execute the same jobs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm hoping to leverage GitLab CI/CD / gitlab-runner to keep custom code up to date on a fleet of servers.

Desired effect is that when a commit is made against a certain project in GitLab, several servers then automatically pull those changes down.

Is it possible to leverage gitlab-runner's in this way, so that every runner registered with the project executes the contents of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? Or is there a better tool to accomplish this?

I could use Ansible to push updates files down to each server, but I was looking for something easier to solve for - something inherent in GitLab.

**Edit: Alternative Solution**

I decided to go the route of pre- and post-hook files in my repos as described here:

https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa

Basically I will be denoting a primary server as the main source for code pushes into the master repo, and have defined my entire fleet as remote repos in .git/config there. Using post-hooks inside of bare repo's on all of my servers, I can then copy my code into the proper execution path.

Comment: I think it's better to have a single runner and trigger the pull in the servers from the runner

Comment: Is it not possible to have all runners registered to a project process the pipeline?

Comment: Yes you can for example using [shell](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) but you need to manage X runners on X server. Do you want to do this ?

Comment: Yep. I can easily automate the process of deploying and registering runners so that one lives on every server in my fleet. Then the idea is the job on each runner is the same - pull from git and copy my code into the proper directory on that server. Looking through the shell executor, and the gitlab-runner documentation in general, I don't see any control parameters that force multiple (all) runners in a project to all execute - seems like the first runner that grabs the job runs with it, and then the pipeline is complete.

Comment: Maybe your problem could be resolved client-side? Periodically pulling code or using some ideas from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978400/git-auto-pull-from-repository). If you handle it outside of gitlab you don't have to worry about updating your pipelines, you just spawn your serwers and let them handle pulling changes from repository.

Answer (score 2):

@ahxn81 Runners aren't really intended to be used in the pull way you describe. The Ansible push method you proposed is more in line with typical deploy flow. I can see why you might prefer the simplicity of the pull method over pushing via script. I guess a fleet of servers these days is via kubernetes or docker swarm which can simplify deployment after an initial setup headache.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. That is the conclusion I ultimately reached. I spent a few hours reading about GitLab CI/CD and how to setup runners. As an Ops guy, I never saw any clarification on the fundamentals of how this would typically work. Probably because people with a Dev background already have that fundamental understanding.