# Automatically push the code on the server when the remote github repository is updated

Tags: django, git, github, github-actions, hook

Automatically fetch the code on server from Github when the repository is updated on Github
I have deployed my project on server. There are more multiple contributors in this project now, so we make changes in our local machine and then push those changes on the github. How can I create a workflow where every time the github repository is updated with latest push from local repository, the repository on my server also get those changes automatically?
Does git have any feature to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For continuous integration and continuous delivery (CI/CD), you can utilize a CI/CD tool such as Jenkins, CircleCI, GitHub Actions, and others. Among these options, [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) stands out as the easiest tool to get started with, thanks to its simpler configuration process.

Here is a sample code to help you get started.

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build_deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16
    - run: |
        cd scripts
        chmod +x ./deploy.sh
        chmod +x ./build.sh
        ./deploy.sh prod ${{ secrets.DOMAIN_NAME }}
      shell: bash
      env:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: 'us-east-1'
```

I have written some bash scripts to build and deploy the code, which I then placed on the server. In the above code, what I did was invoke those scripts whenever new code is pushed into the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

**My Suggestions:**

This is not the best approach but you could right a bash/shell script on your server and make it run behind a cron job that checks for new changes on your remote repository and pull it if the branch or current commit is behind the updated one.

The other way is having a web hook or polling using Jenkins. You could configure a job in Jenkins that could poll (polls the remote repository at set intervals to check for changes and pulls/runs the job when changes found) or listen to GitHub repository changes using webhook (For this you need to make sure that GitHub can reach your Jenkins URL (Server), if your Jenkins is configured on local network you will need to proxy it to make it available publicly, or if it is on cloud then this is not a problem.

**Already Answered , I'll say one of the good ones:**
[StackOverFlow Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9978442/14589948)

Git has "hooks", actions that can be executed after other actions. What you seem to be looking for is "post-receive hook". In the github admin, you can set up a post-receive url that will be hit (with a payload containing data about what was just pushed) everytime somebody pushes to your repo.

For what it's worth, I don't think auto-pull is a good idea -- what if something wrong was pushed to your branch ? I'd use a tool like capistrano (or an equivalent) for such things.